# Jquery - Automatic click in third party site

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to click a link in other site.

```
<a href='https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=apple&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZV-9WJLODa2l8weF86joBg'/>
```

Above anchor tag will open the google search.
But i want to open the first search result automatically.

Is there any way to inject the Jquery(to open first search automatically) while user clicking the link

Comment: you're asking how to inject script into another website? That's a form of hacking (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You could do this with some server-side script - call the Google search using cURL or something, parse the result and redirect the user to the URL of the first result. Or use the search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) to build something that does it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible, and that's a good thing. Just think about the security implications if this were actually possible: anyone could remote control your browser to click on any link they want.